# Magento 2 : Add Custom Tax Amount To Shipping Tax In Order

Tags: magento2, shipping, tax

Does Anyone know how  can i add custom tax amount to shipping tax in magento2 order ?

Total Tax Amount  20
   Shipping Tax : 10
   Other Tax :    10

Comment: is shipping tax is static 10?

Comment: Yes Shipping tax is now static and I have to add custom tax to that static shipping tax